# Displaying dates using vbnewline in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two datetime pickers in vb.net that calculate the number of days between two dates and display in a message box the number of days. I want the number to display in a text box using vbnewline or any method but NOT to display in a messageBox

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles btnCalculate.Click

        If True Then

            Dim dt1 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Text)

            Dim dt2 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Text)

            Dim ts As TimeSpan = dt2.Subtract(dt1)

            If Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days) >= 0 Then

                MessageBox.Show("Total Days are " & Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days))

            Else

                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input")

            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

Any input appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use [**`Environment.NewLine`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

```
TextBox1.Text = "Total Days are"

TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days))
```

Comment: Another thing is there a way to prevent a user from selecting morethan 10 days from these two dates? if he select a number grater than ten days an alert pops up and hes return to select again

Comment: @Jesty-First mark this as an answer If you got the answer for this question and please do post another question for the remaining doubts you have based on this

Comment: beside my answer on left hand side you will find an up arrow and down arrow along with that you will find a tick mark below that...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused. You can show the info in a `TextBox`, a `MessageBox` or a `Label`, but `vbNewLine` is just a constant that represents a line break, so you can use it with any of the previous controls.

Just put a TextBox usign the designer and then change the line

`MessageBox.Show("Total Days are " & Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days))`

with this:

`YourTextBox.Text = "Total ......"`

Good luck but do a little research the next time.